# Java DefaultHttpClient HTTP PUT and Cookie

Tags: java, put, youtrack

I'm send a request to YouTrack api to create issue.

```
    String url = yBaseUrl + "/rest/issue?Task&"+ URLEncoder.encode(subject)+"&"+URLEncoder.encode(desc);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPut request = new HttpPut(url);

    // add request header
    ((DefaultHttpClient) client).setCookieStore(cookie);
    HttpResponse response = null;
    //client.execute(post);
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

result - 403 code.

Why setCookieStore not working?

Comment: what is this cookie? many be it is not properly set

Comment: 403 means forbidden error, maybe you're not setting correct headers/cookie values according to api requirements. You need to check that.

Comment: I'm get cookies:
   public static CookieStore getCookieYoutrack(String baseurl, String login, String password) throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      ......

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        CookieStore cookieStore = ((DefaultHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore();
        return cookieStore;
    }

setCookieStore whith GET - worked, PUT - not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was incorrect api url. Need use /rest/issue?**project**=Task&**summary**="+ URLEncoder.encode(subject)... The question is closed